# Flutter/Dart - Vertically Centre Gridview

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to centre a gridview in the centre of my scaffold but I am struggling to achieve this. I have tried wrapping in a Container with the alignment arguments as well as in a column and centre widgets. I have only been able to align my gridview in the centre horizontally. Can someone help? Here is my code:

```
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My gridview"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          height: double.infinity,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text("Row Item 1"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                                              Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          height: double.infinity,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text("RowItem2"),
                                 
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              //CENTRE THE BELOW WIDGET IN MIDDLE OF SCREEN
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 10,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                      //The maximum horizontal width of a single child Widget
                      maxCrossAxisExtent: 50,
                      // horizontal spacing between individual child widgets
                      mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                      //Vertical vertical spacing between individual child widgets
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(
                         
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              index.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, maybe your widget is taking constraints from its parents

```
SizedBox(
   width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child:Wrap(
     alignment: WrapAlignment.start
     children:[
              //CENTRE THE BELOW WIDGET IN MIDDLE OF SCREEN
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 10,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                      //The maximum horizontal width of a single child Widget
                      maxCrossAxisExtent: 50,
                      // horizontal spacing between individual child widgets
                      mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                      //Vertical vertical spacing between individual child widgets
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(
                         
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              index.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              )        
     ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try using a stack, As there is not pictorial representation of your expected result, I have tried according to your question statement, the code is here as follows (The colors have been changed for reference).

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My gridview"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text("Row Item 1"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text("RowItem2"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05),
                child: Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: 100,
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                        //The maximum horizontal width of a single child Widget
                        maxCrossAxisExtent: 50,
                        // horizontal spacing between individual child widgets
                        mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                        //Vertical vertical spacing between individual child widgets
                        crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              index.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]